# Fiddler doesn't work on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, debugging, web

I can't get Fidller to show any traffic whatsoever when installed on Server 2012 Standard.
Any hints on what needs to be enabled or disabled or clicked to make it functional?

Just in case, Fiddler version is v4.4.8.0.

Comment: We really need more detail before any useful answers can be given. Logs, error messages, indications of what you've done so far. There's a helpful summary available: http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm sorta stuck on this one - there are no logs or errors, it just doesn't show any traffic except for a call to telerik.com/updateCheck on start. I've googled, but didn't find anything related.

Comment: I'm having same problem on windows server 2012. It caught all traffic from a local browser fine but failed to catch outbound service calls from IIS in that windows 2012 server. I searched around but couldn't find anything about windows 2012 (most of them are about windows 8).

Comment: You need to set.machine config to route other users into the proxy.. but even after I did that, Fiddler didnt work on the server. This does work on my local machine IIS though... not sure..